# What is a representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, representation-theory

I know the definition is given as follows:

A map $p: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ such that $p(g_1g_2)=p(g_1)p(g_2)$ but I still do not really understand what this means

Can someone help me gain some intuition for this - perhaps a basic example?

Thanks

Comment: To give you some intuition, let $V$ be finite dimensional. Then $GL(V)$ is just invertible $n\times n$ matrices. So what $p$ is doing in this case is representing the multiplication in your abstract group $G$ by the very concrete multiplication of invertible matrices...

Comment: It means that in any matrix representation of a group it is matrix multiplication that should be the equivalent to performing the group operation.

Comment: A homomorphism from the group into a matrix group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a favorite example, or rather pair of examples that I like to use to motivate looking at representations assuming a bit of familiarity with groups.

The first thing I want to consider is the full symmetry group of a regular tetrahedron, where by full I mean "allowing reflections". In this case it's easy to see that we can order the four vertices in any way and the full symmetry group is the symmetric group $S_4$.

Next let's consider the group of rotational symmetries of a cube, where by rotational I mean, you guessed it, "not allowing reflections". It's easy to see that there are 24 such symmetries (by looking at say the "top face"), with a little more work you can also see that this group is again $S_4$ (hint: look at the space diagonals).

So somehow we have the same group arising as the symmetries of objects in two ways that feel very different in some sense, for one thing one has reflections and the other does not.  If instead of talking about symmetries of a tetrahedron/cube we talk of symmetries of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that preserve the tetrahedron/cube, then we have two copies of $S_4$ in $GL_3(\mathbb{R})$ (or even $O(3)$) which we can think of as maps (homomorphisms) $S_4 \to GL_3(\mathbb{R})$. Such maps into $GL_n$ are called representations.  The point of this example is that while the underlying groups here are the same, the representations are not.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition is that $G$ is the group of symmetry of something. For example, if you study classical physics, it may be the group of Euclidean transformations. $V$ is a space whose elements are objects (velocity, force, electron in quantum mechanics,...) as seen by an observer. The action of the group corresponds to a change of observer. A different observer sees the "vector" differently. But the change is assumed to be linear and invertible, with analogy of elementary change of basis in linear algebra. Everybody "sees" the zero vector as zero. (There is "no force" / "no electron" etc)

Whatever is an electron, if it is a "vector" and you want to operate in the special relativity framework, then the underlying vector space should be a representation of the Poincaré group (elements of Poincaré group=change of observers in special relativity). Quantum people also require a scalar product such that $\langle gx, gy\rangle=\langle x, y\rangle$ for any $g\in G$, $x,y\in V$. This gives you restriction, which spaces are possible as models for some objects.

(At least this is my understanding of the motivation from physics, and why unitary representations of $SL(2,\Bbb C)$ were so much studied: ($SL(2,\Bbb C)=Spin(3,1)$, a double-cover of the Lorentz group).)

Answer (score 0):

Building off of my comment, the easiest non-trivial example I can think of is that of a finite cyclic group. Since a cyclic group is generated by a single element, we only need to say where the generator goes. Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $2$, with generator $x$. Then $x\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ defines a map $p:G\to GL_2$, and thus a 2-dimensional representation. Even more simply, you can take $x\mapsto [-1]$ where here we are viewing $[-1]$ as a $1\times 1$ matrix; thus we have a 1-dimensional representation of $G$ by $GL_1$.

Note: The condition you write $p(g_1g_2) = p(g_1)p(g_2)$ is saying that $p$ has to be a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a little bit of group theory your familiar with the idea of homomorphism.

Now the idea of a linear representation is to take a group and find a homomorphism to a group of linear operators on a vector space. If you've fixed a basis then you're finding a homomorphism to a matrix group. If the vector space is $n$ dimensional, then the matrices are $n\times n$.

To be honest the simplest representation I can think of other than of the trivial group, is of $S_2$, the permutations of two numbers $\{1,2\}$. This is the group $\Bbb Z_2$ but I think permutations are more intuitive.

So if you want to think intuitively (for me at least) think of $S_2$ permuting the fixed basis say $\{e_1,e_2\}$ of a two dimensional space.

Then the $id$ element should leave the basis alone and so is just mapped to the identity matrix under our map $\rho$. Now for a non trivial representation the other permutation should swap the two basis elements and so should map to $$\left( \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1  \\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right).$$

Then in fact there is a natural representation of $S_n$ on an $n$ dim vector space, where fixing a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$, where for $\sigma\in S_n$, let $\rho(\sigma) (e_i)= e_{\sigma(i)}$.